# Python - ImportError: cannot import name - another question

Tags: python

I've seen dozens of questions like this with different problems / solutions. After going through the first dozen or so on StackOverflow, I haven't found a solution to my problem which is:

I have a class like this:

```
class Flight:
    pass
```

in a file called `airtravel.py` and then on my REPL (in that directory) I use:

```
from airtravel import Flight
```

which immediately fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Flight
>>>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such library in Python and PyPi - https://pypi.org/search/?q=airtravel

Comment: Clarified my question.

Comment: `from` and `import` are for libraries, not for files)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are both on the same directory. Your `main.py` And `airtravel.py`

Answer (score 0):

There's several reasons this can happen. Since it's not a `ModuleNotFoundError` I can think of two things you can try:

1. Make sure you've spelled `Flight` correctly in both places. If that doesn't solve your problem then
2. Change the name of the module from `airtravel` to something else like `airtravel2`. The reason for this is that there's a possibility that there's another module named `airtravel` somewhere else, and is being imported because of higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below suggestion and see if it helps.

1. Probably latest content of your file `airtravel.py` is not Saved.
2. Try renaming your file `airtravel.py` to some other name say `airtraveltest.py`